# Issues posting comment with ajax through django

Tags: ajax, django, modelform

I am relatively new to this, but I'm working through things.  I want to get solid understanding of how things work.

That being said, I have been attempting to get Django to post comments with an ajax hook.

I thought I was close to accomplishing this but, nothing so far.  I was able to write a view that would save a posted comment then redirect me to my main page.  I want to be able to use ajax so that the comment would post in a facebook style.

```
def add_comment(request, pk):
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
      comment = comment_form.save(commit=True)
      comment.save()
    json = simplejson.dumps(comment, ensure_ascii=False)
   return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
  return render_to_response(simplejson.dumps('{{ post.id }}', {'comment': comment,}), context_instance=RequestContext(request), mimetype='application/json')
```

This view is pretty rough right now.  I don't have any calls to json but, read this might be the way to go.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script></javascript>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).click(function()
  {
   $('#comment_form').submit(function()
   {
    var dataString = $('#comment_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{ post.id }}',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data){
        $('{{ post.id }}').html(data);
      },
    });
    return false;
    });
  });

</script>

 <form action="" method="POST" id="comment_form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div id="cform">
      Name: {{ form.author }}
      <p>{{ form.body|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: It's easier to get help if you post code. Without that, the best I can do is punch Google for you: http://brandonkonkle.com/blog/2009/feb/16/ajax-django-comments-jquery/

Comment: I was just about to add the code a few minutes ago, then the service provider went down the crapper.

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way.  I've read through this page, along with any other one to come up with the search words for ajax django post comments(in that order or many others).  The main issues are in the view.  I'm using posts.id/foreignkey to direct the comment.

Comment: I'm going through the documentation in jquery and now I think I should be adding .post in the function.  I'm still unclear about the view.

Comment: Please post your comments list and form templates as well as the template that calls both. TYIA

Comment: Using firebug, I had a hunch the url would cause an issue.  Firebug is saying the url isn't correct.

Comment: Hey jpic, heres the comment_form but, not sure what you mean by comment list.

Comment: Update, I got the comment to send to the proper page.  I have a firebug going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response, next time I will definitely leave a more detailed post.  My problem was in the jquery script.  I was trying to pass dataString as form data to the view, when it was a DOM object not the actual form data.  Here's the final working script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#comment_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url art.views.post %}',
    data: $('#comment_form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
      location.reload();
$('#comment_form').get(0).reset();
  },
 });
 return false;
 });
});
```